# Par value less than annual dividend for preferred stocks?

Tags: stocks, investing, dividends

Hey I am just skimming through the chapter 18 of the book intelligent investor by benjamin graham with commentary Jason Zweig. **Pg:447** It basically compares Real Estate Investment Trust with Realty Equities Corp.of New York.
It says that Realty Equities Corp entered to miscellany of ventures, backed by
variety of corporate devices including.
**1. A preferred stock entitled to $7 annual dividends, but with a
par value of only $1, and carried as a liability at $1 per share.**

What does this statement even mean? Does that mean that if I buy one preferred stock with preferred stock with $1 par or face value, then I will get $7 annual dividend? It seems ridiculous.
And what extra information does  liability at $1 per share give other than the preferred stock was issued with par value of $1 per share?
[image: Pg 447 of the book]

Answer (score 3):

It means that if you buy this preferred stock with a par value of $1 you should get a dividend of $7 per year. However, if the company does not do well, your dividend may not be there.

Just because it has a par value of $1, does not mean that you can buy it for $1.  If we are talking about a quality company where the dividend is secure I would expect the price of this preferred stock to be at least $100 maybe $200.

The par value of the stock is not of much interest to the investor. It is used in the companies accounting statements. If I bought a preferred stock with a par value of $1 and the company went bankrupt, I would expect to get at most the par value of the stock. In reality, since preferred stock holders are subordinate to bond holders, if I owned preferred stock in a company that went bankrupt, I would not expect to get anything.